# "With Mary talking" or "Mary talking"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a question about a sentence with participle in an adverb phrase.

When you are describing people who just had a meal at a restaurant in the neighborhood, can you say either sentence?

> John and Mary walked home, **with Mary** still talking about how good the
> food was.
>
> John and Mary walked home, **Mary** still talking about how good the food
> was.

I am not sure if there should be "with" in the sentence before Mary, to specify that it was Mary, not John, who was talking.

Comment: Either one is fine, and either one makes it clear that Mary was talking.

Comment: Consider the statement *Caviar being expensive, I don't often eat it* - which can optionally be preceded by ***With...*** (or more colloquially, ***What with...***). Whether or not the extra word/s are present makes no difference to the meaning.